# c++ best way to define a type consisting of a set of fixed integers

Tags: c++

i need to work with "indicator" variables `I` that may take on one of 3 integer values {-1, 0, 1}.

so i would rather not declare
`int I;`

but rather
`indicator_t I;`

where the type `indicator_t` ~ {-1, 0, 1}

if furthermore i can later use `I` in numerical expressions, as an integer (without casting?), that would be excellent.

question:

how should i define the type `indicator_t`?

Comment: Do you want your tri-state input to come from runtime integral values (e.g. from `int` input), or will it always be assigned via literals (`-1`, `0`, `1`)? You might be able to get away with simply defining an `enum class` with 3 discriminators, and a free function to convert between ints and the enum

Comment: @Human-Compiler thanks, it will always come from literals. ok, enums with converters sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to convert the tri-state input into an `enum class` with 3 fixed discriminators:

```cpp
enum class indicator_t {
    negative = -1,
    zero = 0,
    positive = 1,
};
```

There are several nice things with this approach:

- It's simple, which makes it easy to understand and maintain
- `enum class` makes it a unique type from `int`s, which allow both the enum and an integer to appear as part of an overload set, if needed
- The `enum` logically has a cardinality of 3 (the type can accept 3 logical inputs). <sup>1</sup>

  - This cardinality prevents code that would otherwise be like `a != 2`<sup>2</sup> even though `2` is never a possible input
- When inputs are passed to a function accepting `indicator_t`, it's clear from the call-site the intention. Consider the difference between the following two code snippets:

  ```cpp
  accept(1); // is this an indicator?
  accept(indicator_t::positive); // ah, it's an indicator
  ```

If you need to convert to / from numeric values, you can create simple wrappers for this as well:

```cpp
auto to_int(indicator_t indicator) -> int
{
   return static_cast<int>(indicator);
}
auto to_indicator(int indicator) -> indicator_t
{
    if (indicator > 1 || indicator < -1) {
        // handle error. Throw an exception? 
    }
    return static_cast<indicator_t>(indicator);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Technically* C++ enums can take on any integral value that fits in `std::underlying_type_t<the_enum>`, but this doesn't change that the *logical* valid set of inputs is fixed, which prevents developer bugs. Compilers will even try to warn on checks outside of the logical range.

<sup>2</sup> Technically this could still be done, but you'd need to explicitly `static_cast` all the time -- so it would appear as a code smell rather than a silently missed logic bug.

Comment: (the "at" symbol somehow does not work, name is suppressed when used) Human-Compiler there is no way i can just say ```I = -1;``` or ```int S = I + 1;``` without wrappers or casts, correct?

Comment: Not with an `enum class` specifically. You could use just plain old `enum` from C, which will allow it to be implicitly converted from integers -- but C `enum`s have a lot of issues that `enum class`es fix (like name scoping and better type-safety). Between the two, IMO it'd be better to stick with `enum class` and just use the explicit discriminators or the casts when needed

Comment: (at)Human-Compiler would a C style enum class catch ```I = -2;``` as an error?

Comment: @newbie You don't need the @ symbol if you want to answer to the post author, they will get your comment regardless.